# Unifying Heterogeneous Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

In my MySQL database I have a table of `products` along the lines of

```
id | type | name | weight | base_price | [...]
```

where `id` is a primary key and `type` is an `ENUM('personal','industrial')`.  Personal and industrial products both have some additional information stored in `products_personal` and `products_industrial` tables.  Both are of the form

```
pid | additional info [...]
```

where `pid` is foreign keyed with `products.id` and additional info is different for `products_personal` and `products_industrial`.  In my table I have two functions (through `CREATE FUNCTION`), `PRICE_PERSONAL(...)` and `PRICE_INDUSTRIAL(...)`.  These functions use the `base_price` and some of the additional info to compute a final price.

I wish to create a view of `id | type | name | [...] | price` for all of my products.  My current candidate is

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS

SELECT id, type, name, [...], PRICE_PERSONAL(params) AS price
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_personal ON products.id = products_personal.pid

UNION

SELECT id, type, name, [...], PRICE_INDUSTRIAL(params) AS price
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_industrial ON products.id = products_industrial.pid
```

But this is a but bulky and seems to result in poor `ORDER BY` performance (as it needs to sort the un-indexed `UNION` results).

Is there a cleaner table or query structure to accomplish this type of query?

Comment: You can turn that into `UNION ALL` - so no sorting is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't actually test it, but try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS

SELECT id, type, name, [...], PRICE_PERSONAL(params) AS price
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_personal ON products.id = products_personal.pid
WHERE type = 'personal'

UNION ALL

SELECT id, type, name, [...], PRICE_INDUSTRIAL(params) AS price
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_industrial ON products.id = products_industrial.pid
WHERE type = 'industrial'
```

The idea is to cut-off "wrong" rows early by filtering on `products.type`. Also, I should give credit to @ypercube for spotting `UNION ALL`.

What are the fields under `ORDER BY`? They should probably be indexed.